# Rename file in Mac OS Terminal using Regex or translate from Windows Script

Tags: files, regular-expression, rename, macos

I would like help with a shell script for macOS to rename files with a certain pattern. The script would handle only one file, not multiple.

Here are three examples:

a. Public Talks_ (189) Walking With God Brings Blessings Now and Forever — Chris Ruscher 10_28_2023.mp3

> would become
>
> 189 - Walking With God Brings Blessings Now and Forever - Chris Ruscher - 2023-10-28-0900.mp3

b. Public Talks_ (55) How Can You Make a Good Name With God? — Gregory Duhon 11_4_2023.mp3

> would become
>
> 055 - How Can You Make a Good Name With God? - Gregory Duhon - 2023-11-04-0900.mp3

c. Public Talks_ (9) Walking With God Brings Blessings Now and Forever — Chris Ruscher 10_28_2023.mp3

> would become
>
> 009 - Walking With God Brings Blessings Now and Forever - Chris Ruscher - 2023-10-28-0900.mp3

So in essence, the final format and order should be: `track number`, `title`, `speaker name`, and `timestamp`.

1. drop the prefix “Public Talks_ “
2. Isolate the track number as a 3 digit number with leading zeros as needed
3. Dashes in between all 4 elements
4. Reformat date to a timestamp like yyyy-mm-dd-0900

I would then take the shell script and use it per file in this dialog box (no need to iterate):

*Please note the variable for the file being passed on to the shell script needs to be written as "$1" as seen in the dialog box below.*

[image: insert shell script window]

Someone helped me create one but it only works for Windows and doesn't take into account "$1" as the file and is set to do multiple files. I need it to work on macOS for one file at a time.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.mp3; do
    # Remove "Public Talks_"
    newname=${file#"Public Talks_ "}
    # Extract the track number and pad with leading zeros
    track=$(echo $newname | grep -o -E '\([0-9]+\)' | tr -d '()' | awk '{printf "%03d\n", $0}')
    # Remove track number and trailing spaces
    newname=$(echo $newname | sed -E 's/\([0-9]+\)//' | sed 's/^ *//')
    # Extract the title and speaker
    title=$(echo $newname | awk -F 'â€”' '{print $1}' | sed 's/ *$//')
    speaker=$(echo $newname | awk -F 'â€”' '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1, $2}')
    # Extract the date and reformat
    date=$(echo $newname | grep -o -E '[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+' | tr '_' '-' | awk -F- '{print $3"-"$1"-"$2"-0900"}')
    # Concatenate all elements with dashes
    newname="$track - $title - $speaker - $date.mp3"
    # Rename the file
    mv "$file" "$newname"
done
```

Can anyone translate it into the proper macOS syntax or write a shell script that is even more concise?

Comment: Note that your input file names seem to contain `—` (U+2014 em dash) characters while your expected  output expects `-` (U+002D regular hyphen-minus). That `awk -F 'â€”'` doesn't make sense other than it seems to be the double-encoding of *em dash* via the windows-1252 charset (as in `echo — | iconv -t utf-8 | iconv -f windows-1252 -t utf-8`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I agree. I went back to your zmv code and **it is perfect!** I adjusted it to give 2 digit month and year. And it works flawlessly, when I use it in Terminal. However, I want to use it as a Folder Action in the Mac Finder. When I do, it errors out to "[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil objects[0]". Would you have any ideas?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - Here is the tweaked code:
`zmv '*_ \((<0-999>)\)(* )—( * )(<1-12>)_(<1-31>)_(<1900-2100>)(.mp3)' '${(l[3][0])1} -$2-$3- $6-${(l[2][0])5}-${(l[2][0])4}-0900$7'`

Comment: Ah. Thanks, I had missed that requirement, I've added it to my answer. No idea about your Mac Finder issue, I don't have access to macos machines.

Comment: Understood. Many, many thanks for the help. It was invaluable. Hopefully someone else can help with the Mac issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In zsh, from within the directory that contains those files, you'd run:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -n '*_ \((<0-999>)\)(* )—( * )(<1-12>)_(<1-31>)_(<1900-2100>)(.mp3)' \
       '${(l[3][0])1} -$2-$3- $6-${(l[2][0])5}-${(l[2][0])4}-0900$7'
```

Example:

```
$ autoload -Uz zmv
$ zmv -n '*_ \((<0-999>)\)(* )—( * )(<1-12>)_(<1-31>)_(<1900-2100>)(.mp3)' \
         '${(l[3][0])1} -$2-$3- $6-${(l[2][0])5}-${(l[2][0])4}-0900$7'
mv -- 'Public Talks_ (189) Walking With God Brings Blessings Now and Forever — Chris Ruscher 10_28_2023.mp3' '189 - Walking With God Brings Blessings Now and Forever - Chris Ruscher - 2023-28-10-0900.mp3'
mv -- 'Public Talks_ (55) How Can You Make a Good Name With God? — Gregory Duhon 11_4_2023.mp3' '055 - How Can You Make a Good Name With God? - Gregory Duhon - 2023-4-11-0900.mp3'
mv -- 'Public Talks_ (9) Walking With God Brings Blessings Now and Forever — Chris Ruscher 10_28_2023.mp3' '009 - Walking With God Brings Blessings Now and Forever - Chris Ruscher - 2023-28-10-0900.mp3'
```

Remove the `-n` (dry-run) if happy.

If that has to be a shell script that takes the file names as arguments:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
set -o extendedglob
pattern='(#b)*_ \((<0-999>)\)(* )—( * )(<1-12>)_(<1-31>)_(<1900-2100>)(.mp3)'
ret=0
for file {
  if [[ $file = $~pattern ]] {
    argv=( "$match[@]" )
    mv -i -- $file "${(l[3][0])1} -$2-$3- $6-${(l[2][0])5}-${(l[2][0])4}-0900$7" || ret=$?
  } else {
    print -ru2 "Skipping $file which doesn't match the pattern"
  }
}
exit $ret
```

But you'd be missing on the extra safeguards of `zmv`.

Note that we're looping over all the arguments of the script instead of just processing the first (`$1`).

Comment: Thank you for the response. It errored out. Your code doesn't seem to have the $1 variable.

Comment: @AllexValentin, that's what that zmv command does. Here I show its dry-run output which shows the `mv` command it would run  on those three files.

Comment: Understood. Thank you! Can you adjust for the $1 variable. I think that is where the error comes from.

Comment: See if the edit makes it clearer. `$1` is not a variable, it expands to the first argument of a script/function or to the empty string if the script is not passed any  argument (in zsh, `$1` is short for `$argv[1]`, `argv`  being actually treated as a variable). In the example script I give, we're looping over all the arguments ($1, $2...) with `for file`, not just processing the first ($1) so you can call it with `that-script *.mp3`.

Comment: See how we actually do `argv=( "$match[@]" )` so we can write `$1` `$2`... on the next line instead of `$match[1]` `$match[2]`

Comment: You are awesome! I am new to this and trying to understand everything.

Unfortunately, in the app I am using to handle the files, it is not renaming. It runs without error, but it also doesn't rename the file. I am trying to see where the error is. I am confident your code is perfect.

I adjusted it like this:
`set -o extendedglob
pattern='(#b)*_ \((<0-999>)\)(* )—( * )(<1-12>)_(<1-31>)_(<1900-2100>)(.mp3)'
ret=0
  if [[ $1 = $~pattern ]] {
    argv=( "$match[@]" )
    mv -i -- $1 "${(l[3][0])1} -$2-$3- $6-$5-$4-0900$7" || ret=$?
  }
exit $ret`

Comment: @AllexValentin add a `set -o xtrace` at the start of the script. Possibly the file you tried it on doesn't match the pattern

Comment: @AllexValentin what exactly is *"the app I am using to handle the files"*?

Comment: @steeldriver, it smells like [this](https://www.noodlesoft.com/manual/hazel/attributes-actions/using-shell-scripts/).